# Is it 'Save time IN your morning routine' or 'Save time ON your morning routine'?

Tags: prepositions

I need help on this.

Do I say

> Save time ***in*** your morning routine

or

> Save time ***on*** your morning routine

?

The context: a beauty procedure that simplifies women's makeup routine.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**On** would be the best preposition. You usually use *In* when referring to periods of time such as seasons, months, centuries, etc. whereas **On** is used to describe scenarios of "close proximity" or specific descriptions of time such as days or parts of the day. One exception is when using it for "in the morning", "in the afternoon". But your sentence is not using it in that way, so the best choice would be **On**.